# pyinstaller exe file don't work with pyaudio - speech recognition

Tags: pyinstaller, pyaudio

Hi i am a intermediate python developer and I made a voice paint app that you can control app with voice , for this app i used speech recognition for my app and speech recognition needs pyaudio .
for installing pyaudio i couldn't use pip or pipwin and i installed it using .whl file downloaded from internet and it works!
now in my app when I run it in python ide or vs code it works but when i use pyinstaller to get exe it gives error ( no module named pyaudio )
i tried lots of ways but none worked.
can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question, when you say "i tried lots of ways but none worked"; did this include adding pyaudio to a pyinstaller hook?

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files,collect_submodules

#should only require hiddenimports
#datas = collect_data_files('pyaudio')
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pyaudio')
```